# How to fix memory leak in my vue.js / axios app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a single page which displays a list of rows from a table using an inline vue.js script, it fetches the list of rows on page load, but also fetches the table again when pusher events are received.

I have a modal window that opens and allows the user to add new people to the table. When the user presses submit (on the form) the modal posts an ajax request (using axios) to submit the record. This sends a `App\Events\NewQueueMember` event to Pusher which my vue app also listens for and when this occurs the `updateData` method is called to refresh the table.

The problem I have is when the form is submitted, the page because somewhat unresponsive for about 5 seconds before then being able to scroll on the page again. Looking at Chromes Task manager I can see the RAM usage for the tab doubles and the CPU usage is considerably high too.

I believe its some sort of memory leak but I'm not sure how to resolve and would appreciate some guidance.

**This is the form that resides within my modal.**

@csrf
    
        Customer Name
        
        Name will be displayed internally and to the customer

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="add-person-mobile">Mobile Number</label>
    <input type="phone" class="form-control" name="phone_number" id="add-person-mobile"
           v-model="addPersonForm.phone_number">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Please ensure number starts with +44 </small>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="add-person-party-size">Party Size</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="party_size" id="add-person-party-size"
           v-model="addPersonForm.party_size">
</div>
```

**This is the vue.js script block that sites within the same page**

```
<script>

    Vue.use(VueTimeago, {
        name: 'Timeago',
    })

    let vm = new Vue({
        el: '#app',

        data() {
            return {
                live_count: null,
                queue: null,
                loading: true,
                errored: false,
                buttons: {
                    add_to_queue_label: 'Add to Queue',
                    add_to_queue_disabled: false
                },
                addPersonForm: {
                    name: '',
                    phone_number: '',
                    party_size: ''
                }
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            axios
                .get(`/business/queue-live-feed`)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log('got response data')
                    console.log(response.data)
                    this.queue = response.data.queue
                    this.live_count = response.data.live_count
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                    this.errored = true
                })
                .finally(() => this.loading = false);
        },
        
        methods: {
            updateData: function () {
                axios.get(`/business/queue-live-feed`)
                    .then(response => {
                        this.queue = response.data.queue
                        this.live_count = response.data.live_count
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error)
                        this.errored = true
                    });
            },

            addPerson: function (event) {
                console.log('calling resource...');
                this.buttons.add_to_queue_disabled = true;
                this.buttons.add_to_queue_label = "Adding...";

                axios.post(`/business/queue/add2`, this.$data.addPersonForm)
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log('got a response!');
                        console.log(response.data);
                        // this.updateData(); <- when I comment this line, the unresponsiveness lasts around 5-10 seconds.
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log('some error happened :(')
                        this.buttons.add_to_queue_disabled = true;
                        this.buttons.add_to_queue_label = "Retry";
                        // $('#manual-add-people').modal('hide');
                        // console.log(error)
                    })
                    .finally(() => {
                        console.log('finished method');
                        this.buttons.add_to_queue_disabled = false;
                        this.buttons.add_to_queue_label = "Add to Queue";
                        $('#manual-add-people').modal('hide');
                    });

                this.addPersonForm = {};
            },

        }
    })


    // PUSHER CODE
    Pusher.logToConsole = true;

    const pusher = new Pusher('{{ env('PUSHER_APP_KEY') }}', {
        cluster: '{{ env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER') }}',
        authEndpoint: '/broadcasting/auth',
        auth: {
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}',
            }
        }
    });

    pusher.subscribe(`private-queue.business.{{ $business_id }}`)
        .bind('App\\Events\\NewQueueMember', (data) => {
            vm.updateData()
        })
        .bind('App\\Events\\QueueMemberKicked', (data) => {
            vm.updateData()
        })
        .bind('App\\Events\\QueueMemberLeft', (data) => {
            vm.updateData()
        })
        .bind('App\\Events\\QueueMemberNoShow', (data) => {
            vm.updateData()
        })
    ;

</script>
```

The method in question is the `addPerson` which is called when the form is submitted.

I believe the issue is related to my usage of `this.$data.addPersonForm`, if I switch this to an empty array.

EDIT:
This is a sample response that comes back from my `/business/queue/add2` endpoint.

```
{guest_id: 55, queue_lane_id: 1, party_size: 2, short_id: "RIS0MRk0",…}
business: {id: 2, name: "Acme Ltd", business_type_id: 2, is_active: 1,…}
business_id: 2
created_at: "2020-09-27T23:53:11.000000Z"
customer: null
guest: {id: 55, name: "AJAX Test 29", phone_number: "+1234567890", business_id: 2,…}
guest_id: 55
id: 79
party_size: 2
queue_entry_time: "2020-09-28 00:53:11"
queue_lane_id: 1
short_id: "RIS0MRk0"
updated_at: "2020-09-27T23:53:11.000000Z"
```

It's just a JSON blob with details of the record they just created, its not really huge either.

I have also updated the Vue script above to reflect the additional method call I made in my `then()` function under `addPerson`.

Comment: how did you come to conclusion that usage of `this.$data.addPersonForm` is causing issue? Did you try with using mock data and check if page is still unresponsive? Also, if you could share codesandbox to see the issue that would help.

Comment: When I change that variable to a empty list, the memeory usage doesn’t spike. I’m afk, will update the question tonight.

Comment: Is page still responsive? My money is on `updateData` call in the subscription handler, which could be potential reason for spike in memory usage.

Comment: Have you profiled this altogether? Upon `vm.updateData()` you're making another call to server, I'm curious in case you post an empty user perhaps your endpoint at `/business/queue-live-feed` returns a lot faster compared to posting some proper data.

Comment: why are you using `this.$data.addPersonForm` instead of `this.addPersonForm`? Can you put a debugger breakpoint (or just console.log) the call to `updateData`? perhaps it's being called multiple times and a debounce-ish approach could help

Comment: @DipenShah I have updated the post to include more info, let me know if there is anything more you need. I'll try creating a mockup page on codepen tomorrow, as its all locally built its hard to surface the page online. `updateData` method is more or less identically to the mounted method so I'm unsure why its causing an issue.

Comment: @MaviDomates So I don't actually post any data to `/business/queue-live-feed` queue, its only a GET requst. Its the `add2` endpoint I make a post to. It appears the `updateData` method causes most of the spike but this contents of this method is the same as the `mounted` process so I'm a little confused why it only leaks on the method call and not on load.

Comment: @ffflabs Thats just how I learnt what to use, I have however tried `this.addPersonForm` and this has the same affect. I also do have some debug lines in the method as you can see... and looking at the logs they aren't printed multiple times :(

Comment: You're logging the post request , there's no console statement before axios get

Comment: @InvalidSyntax could you please check in your code you have commented that commenting this line makes page unresponsive by 5-10 is that correct? Did you mean uncommeenting? Also, could you put a console.log right before subscribing to events. I have a doubt you are subscribing multiple times and you can check by monitoring the log statement I want you to add as well as network requests.

Comment: @ffflabs sorry you're right I didnt have a console log in my updateData method, I added one to the top of the method and ran my form submission and it was only run once. What I did find was that 80% of the delay is caused by this method (not the callout itself), but the high memory usage.

Comment: @DipenShah Please see comment above. I don't think its pusher event subscribe that is causing the issue as I have tried simply commenting out all the subscriber events to call the `updateData` method for. It appears the bulk of the process that appears to be leaking is coming from `updateData`. When I dont call this method in `addPerson`, while it still takes about 2 seconds to respond, its much shorter than with `updateData()` inside the `.then` function where the page is unresponsive for more than 5 seconds.

Comment: @InvalidSyntax
Can you post the code/html where this.queue is rendered/used and also any other watchers on this.queue.

I suspect when addPersonForm is an empty array. updateData() is not invoked and this.queue is also not re-rendered.

Comment: Do you have the Vue devtools plugin active? I also had a memory leak problem caused by that plugin -- once I disabled it, the leaks went away.

Answer (score 2):

Inside chrome dev tools, open the "performance" tab, hit record, repeat the issue that is slowing everything down, and then dig into the call stack. Vue might make it a little more confusing to trace since it compiles the code. The chrome "Vue dev tools" might help in this case.

Just from looking at the code, I would also add two different counters and loggers to the updateData() function - log how many times it is being called initially and then log when axios returns. If there's not much data being returned while the function is causing the issue, the pusher might be calling it too many times before it returns. You also might see that in the network tab in dev tools.

Comment: I have run the performance tab, if im honest I'm not really sure what I should be looking at. When I record and run the task as described in my OP, I can see the CPU spikes to 100% for a few seconds but thats all I can really take from it.

Comment: The Vue performance tab shows even less to me, all it does it show me that the post action takes a number seconds to load.

Comment: The general idea is to get a flame graph to analyze the performance of the entire javascript call stack. Firefox also has similar tools - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Performance/Flame_Chart ... Conceptually it will show you how long each function is taking. You could also try logging the start and end of each function, a count of how many times it has been called, and a timestamp with performance.now(). I suspect you are repeatedly calling things - ie:

Comment: something like: console.log('updateDataStart ' + updateDataStart++ + ' ' + performance.now());